# Android GCM registration

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Firstly I launched sample client demo on my phone with my SENDER_ID and received "successful registraion". Then I launch my app with the same SENDER_ID and on the same phone and don't receive nothing. Is that normal? If yes, how do I delete previous registration to fully test my app for push notifications?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try simple things such as uninstalling the sample demo ?

On my side I've restarted my client app several times in a row, obtaining a registration id every time (i.e. you don't need to "delete previous registration").

What's the error you get ? You normally get information when no registration id is returned.

Comment: restarted - you mean "reinstalled"?

Comment: No, I meant restarting a service (kill-start) that registers to Google server.

Comment: I never changed anything on the console after the initial setup. I think you should give a look at what GCM tells you after your registration attempt. There are error codes given back to you in case something goes wrong.